# AccessController.doPrivileged

Tags: java, security, api, jakarta-ee

I am trying to figure out what some legacy code is doing. What exactly is this line doing, and why would I need it this way?

```
String lineSeparator = (String) java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
       new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction("line.separator"));
```

I found it in the logger implementation of the web/ejb application running on Weblogic 8. There are no special security policies enabled as far as I know. (I do not like imports from sun.* packages, so I want to get rid of this line ;-)

Comment: (I very much agree with not using classes from private APIs. Such classes may change or disappear without notice at any time.)

Comment: "\n" at most "\r\n", old times..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is just getting a system property. Retrieving system properties requires permissions which the calling code may not have. The `doPrivileged` asserts the privileges of the calling class irrespective of how it was called. Clearly, `doPrivileged` is something you need to be careful with.

The code quoted is the equivalent of:

```
String lineSeparator = java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
    new java.security.PrivilegedAction<String>() {
        public String run() {
            return System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }
    }
 );
```

(Don't you just love the conciseness of Java's syntax?)

Without asserting privileges, this can be rewritten as:

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Comment: @Tom, "The doPrivileged asserts the privileges of the calling class irrespective of how it was called." What does that mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: I think I meant irrespective of the permissions of the current access control context. So usually when you call a trusted method, the permissions available to that method are those that it was called with. `doPrivileged` starts afresh (although it does include the permission restrictions of the immediate caller).