# Crazy ClassLoader question

Tags: java, classloader, contextclassloader

The classes:

```
public interface Inter {
  ...some methods...
}

public class Impl implements Inter {
  ...some implementations...
}
```

The issue is that for some freaky reason, I have to load the interface `Inter` with **child** ClassLoader and the implementation class `Impl` with **parent** ClassLoader.

In this case I will get `NoClassDefError`, because the parent ClassLoader that is trying to load the implementation `Impl` doesn't know about the interface `Inter` that was loaded in child ClassLoader.

Is there any way of loading the implementation with child ClassLoader (context ClassLoader) ? Or may be I need to write some custom ClassLoader to load both of them (by breaking the delegation rule) ?

Comment: That's just not going to work. You just can't load a class without being able to resolve that class's static dependencies *from that classloader*.

Comment: How about my very last questions about custom ClassLoader ?

Comment: Violating the classloader is not a good idea, infact SecurityManager's can be configured to disable custom classloaders, causing chaos when integrating with other applications. Think of I will provide my own java.lang.String implementation which is loaded into child classloader as the delegation contract no longer applies. 

It may help clear the muck if you can explain the "freaky reason"

Comment: You could implement your own classloader to load *both* of them, but then I don't see the advantage over using the normal classloader to load *both* of them...

Comment: What's the "freaky" reason?  There might be another solution besides doing something weird with class loaders.

Comment: Managed to change the design so it won't have such a strange requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue is that for some freaky
>   reason, I have to load the interface
>   Inter with child ClassLoader and the
>   implementation class Impl with parent 
>   ClassLoader.

I cannot fathom why the child classloader must load the interface, while leaving the parent classloader to load the implementation. This is bound to cause trouble, for *there is no mechanism within the class-loading mechanism utilized by the JVM, to defer loading of classes to a child classloader*. The usual mechanism of implementing the classloading behavior in the JVM is defined in the API documentation of the ClassLoader class:

> The ClassLoader class uses a
>   delegation model to search for classes
>   and resources. Each instance of
>   ClassLoader has an associated parent
>   class loader. When requested to find a
>   class or resource, a ClassLoader
>   instance will delegate the search for
>   the class or resource to its parent
>   class loader before attempting to find
>   the class or resource itself. The
>   virtual machine's built-in class
>   loader, called the "bootstrap class
>   loader", does not itself have a parent
>   but may serve as the parent of a
>   ClassLoader instance.

One can write a custom classloader, by extending the [ClassLoader class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) and overriding the [loadClass() method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String%29). Extending this method allows to you to change the class loading delegation in either of the two ways:

- **Parent-first**: Get the parent classloader to load the class first. This usually is a transitive behavior - most parent classloaders will defer loading to their parent, and so on, until the bootstrap classloader (the root) is reached in the classloader hierarchy. If the parent classloader fails to load the class, the child attempts to load it. An eventual failure in loading the class should result in a ClassNotFoundException being thrown.
- **Parent-last**: The custom classloader attempts to load the class first, before delegating to the parent. The parent classloaders are used only when the child fails in its attempt to load the class.

Most classloaders are implemented as parent-first classloaders. This is due to the fact that the delegation mechanism is able to traverse the tree in the upward direction but not in the downward direction.

If you really wish to delegate loading and finding of classes to child classloaders in the hierarchy, you will have to manage references to them in the custom classloader for the parent. This is not easy, and is usually not done at all except for very exceptional circumstances since it very easy to end up with the dreaded ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError as one must be careful to load only the required classes from the child classloaders, while the rest must always be deferred to the parent (unless I'm mistaken, the feature of shared libraries in certain Java EE containers are implemented this way).

Having said that, the ideal solution would be to attempt loading both the interface and the implementation classes in the parent classloader, and rely on the delegation mechanism to ensure that the classes are visible to both the classloaders; the parent can "see" classes loaded by itself, and the child can "see" the parent's classes.

PS: Don't forget to use [AccessController.doPrivileged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233761/when-should-accesscontroller-doprivileged-be-used) when loading and defining classes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you override the loadClass(String name,boolean resolve) of java.lang.ClassLoader?

I guest you did.

The default behaviour of loading loads the parent class file first,and marks it as loaded one,the loadClass will take loaded class first if found,that's way I guest you override and did not invoke super.loadClass method in customised class loader.

Comment: I didn't write my own class loader. I'm using tomcat, the Impl is loaded with common ClassLoader and the interface is loaded with specific webapp ClassLoader

Comment: Vitaly, that doesn't sound right. If you are loading the implementation yourself, you should try to get ahold of the webapp classloader to do it. Otherwise, if the implementation is somehow automatically loaded by your container, you should put the interface right next to it.