# Difference between session.getServletContext() and session.getServletContext().getContext("/SampleProject")

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a Tomcat 6 instance running on my local machine.

I have made the following changes in its configuration:

- In /conf/`context.xml` – changed the   tag as follows

  ```
  <Context crossContext="true">
  ```
- In /conf/`server.xml`  – changed the   tag as follows

  ```
  <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" emptySessionPath="true"
         connectionTimeout="20000" 
         redirectPort="8443" />
  ```

Suppose I have a WAR file named `SampleProject.war` deployed here which extract to folder `SampleProject`.

In some servlet in this WAR, say `SampleServlet`, I write two blocks of code as follows :

```
ServletContext context1 = session.getServletContext();
```

and

```
ServletContext context2 = session.getServletContext().getContext("/SampleProject");
```

What is the difference between `context1` and `context2`? I thought that both refer to the application context. But if I set some attribute in `context1` and access in `context2`, I don't get the value in `context2`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel your question was slightly misunderstood and that you already had the basic understanding of the API i.e. once a web-app sets its `crossContext="true"` it could use `getContext()` to get access to a context that corresponds to some other web-app deployed on the server.

```
getServletContext().getContext() equals NULL unless <Context crossContext="true">
```

From what I've understood, your question actually is that in `/SameWebApp` why

```
ServletContext context1 = session.getServletContext();
context1.setAttribute("contextAttribute", new Object());
ServletContext context2 = session.getServletContext().getContext("/SameWebApp");

System.out.println(context1.equals(context2)); // prints false, or 
System.out.println(context2.getAttribute("contextAttribute")); // prints null (at least they could have been clones)
```

In just one word, the answer is "Security". Imagine if you couldn't guarantee that an "adminEmail" context attribute has not been tampered with by an *evil* web-app having its `crossContext=true`. Your app could potentially help compromise itself as soon as that "Forgot Password" request comes! :)

### A Dive into Tomcat internals

Tomcat 7 provides a `class ApplicationContext implements ServletContext` that returns from `getContext("/context-root")` as

```
    if (context.getCrossContext()) {
        // If crossContext is enabled, can always return the context
        return child.getServletContext();
    } else if (child == context) {
        // Can still return the current context
        return context.getServletContext();
    } else {
        // Nothing to return
        return (null);
    }
```

Here `context` belongs to current web-app and `child` represents the other web-app. But, hold on, what makes Tomcat call it a child?

These two actually aren't `ApplicationContext` but instances of `StandardContext` a class that `implements Context` but instead of servlet specific things holds Tomcat specific config settings for a web-app like crossContext, hostname, mimeMappings etc. `StandardContext.getParent()` gives you the `Container` and hence it has been referred to as a child above.

Anyways, we're interested in the case when `child == context` is true i.e. `getContext()` was called on the "/***SameWebApp***". The call is being delegated to `StandardContext.getServletContext()` which has been implemented to return a **different instance** of `ApplicationContext`.

***This is why the attributes you set in `context1` are not found in `context2`.***

But wait, there's some more to it. Why does `StandardContext.getServletContext()` return like

```
return (context.getFacade());
```

A Tomcat instance is basically executing two types of Java code:

- container provided, and
- user deployed

The container code is "Trusted" and may need to run with elevated privileges sometimes. The user code, on the other hand, is not trusted and needs to be restricted from compromising Tomcat internals.

One of the things that Tomcat does to achieve this is always wrap an `ApplicationContextFacade` around the `ApplicationContext` (and hence the `StandardContext` as well). So just to recap, what appears to be a simple `ServletContext` implementation is actually a `StandardContext` mapped to an `ApplicationContext` which is then wrapped within an `ApplicationContextFacade`.

For further information on how the `ApplicationContextFacade` works using Reflection in tandem with `Globals.IS_SECURITY_ENABLED` and `SecurityUtil.isPackageProtectionEnabled()` settings please take a look at [Why do Servlets access Tomcat ApplicationContext through a Facade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550804/why-do-servlets-access-the-tomcat-applicationcontext-servletcontext-indirectly) on SO.

References:
[Tomcat 7 Source Code (Download Link)](http://apache.cs.utah.edu/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.39/src/apache-tomcat-7.0.39-src.zip)

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely those two context objects are different from another..
Context1 object gives current web application servlet context obj.
( ServletContext context1 = session.getServletContext();)

and

context2 object gives the servletcontext obj of specified web application 
(ServletContext context2 = session.getServletContext().getContext("/SampleProject");)

you are setting object in one context and trying to retrieve using another context, so it is not possible to get attribute from another web application context by putting it in current application context. But you can get attribute resides in another web application context by using second method.

Comment: But ServletContext context1 = session.getServletContext(); is called in SampleProject so doesn't it point to SampleProject's context?

Comment: As per http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext(java.lang.String) - no, the purpose of this method is to provide access to contexts of other webapps on current web server from current webapp's context.

Answer (score 3):

Think OO & java EE platform standards + security.

The first call returns the *definitive* servlet context for the current app, with all operations supported.

The second call returns a *copy* of the servlet context that could be for any app. As stated (rather vaguely!) in the javadoc, it's purpose is to allow you to obtain a `RequestDispatcher`, so you can dispatch to pages of other apps.  It's other major but implicit requirement is to do this securely and to respect the Java EE specs, which do not allow sharing of session state or servlet context between apps. Imagine the terrible damage "rogue App B" could do to "good App A" if it could just change (or read) Servlet Context data by brute force. That's why it's a copy.

Hence, setting attributes on the copy, does not result in changes to the original.  You could argue that the copy should throw some "Operation Not Supported Exception".  Alternatively, you could argue that getRequestDispatcher should be refactored either to another class, or to allow an App Context URL to be passed in.  ... But, unfortunately, neither of these things are true.  B^)