# Applet calling JS using LiveConnect - does not work outside init()

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, applet, liveconnect

I have an applet running within GWT, I am able to access JS functions from the init() of the applet. But i am unable to use JSObject.call() or JSObject.eval outside the init().

Comment: In a nutshell, the GWT page makes use of this applet to communicate with devices. Once the applet loads as a part of the init() it does a JSObject.call() to notify the GWT code that it has loaded. The GWT code then calls an method on the applet(processSomething()) for some processing, after this processing completes, the applet needs to notify the GWT code again.. this is where I have a problem.. I get a unknown method error while invoking JSObject.call or JSObect.eval from within this processSomething() method..

Comment: netscape.javascript.JSException: Unspecified error invoking method or accessing property "processSomething"

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use **AccessController.doPrivileged()**

Please, read [When should AccessController.doPrivileged() be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233761/when-should-accesscontroller-doprivileged-be-used)