# sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction class in java

Tags: java, string, class

Today I'm learning about IO in java. When I look at `lineSeparator` string in `BufferedWriter` class I saw the statement

```
lineSeparator = java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction("line.separator"));
```

which initialize the `lineSeparator` string. But I don't find

```
sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction(String args)
```

class in java source. So I get confused how java uses this class which is not in java source. So tell me:

- where this classes is defined and how `JVM` call this class ?
- Can we call this class in our own program ?

Comment: @SachinAre you clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has this class you can see from [here](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/action/GetPropertyAction.java), but you shouldn't use sun(now oracle package at your code) [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes) here the reason of why shouldn't use it. And the meaining of

```
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction("line.separator"));
```

> The code that uses doPrivileged says "Give me the value of the
>   property, if the current class (where this line of code is in) is
>   allowed to read it."

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954924/getpropertyaction-vs-system-getproperty-in-obtaining-system-variables) there is another discussion to understand it better

***EDIT :*** It is under your JDK Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\rt.jar you can learn rt.jar [details](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.tr/2015/01/what-is-rtjar-in-javajdkjre-why-its-important.html)

Comment: good explanation, but still I'm unable to understand where "GetPropertyAction" class is defined I mean in which package, JAR or anywhere else in java src folder

Comment: What class can I use to substitute sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction ?

Answer (score 0):

It's 2020 and this still happens. One quick way to resolve the problem is use installed JDK instead of JRE coming from eclipse installation. GoTo Windows>Preferences>Java>Installed JREs and add your installed JDK and use it as default.
[image]