# Whats the fault? :(

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, panel

```
if((wort[0] == "A") && (wort[1] == "P") && (wort[2] == "F") && (wort[3] == "E") && (wort[4] == "L") && (wort[5] == "K") && (wort[6] == "U") && (wort[7] == "C") && (wort[8] == "H") && (wort[9] == "E") && (wort[10] == "N")) {

        frame.remove(panel);
        frame.add(winpanel);
        winpanel.add(winmeldung);
        winpanel.add(beenden);
        frame.validate();
```

Hi,
i have a huge Project here, so i will just post a part of it. I wanted to check something and if it's true a new panel should open. But every time I run i get an error because of "Unknown Source". Why??

EDIT:

the error:

```
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please post the actual error.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete stack trace you get.

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Please post StackTrace.

Comment: You could use `if( wort.equals( "APFELKUCHEN" ) )`

Comment: - What do you mean with "run"? Compile or execute?
- Where is the end of the "if" statement? 
- What type of is wort?

Comment: The stack trace doesn't even mention any of your code. “Unknown Source” simply means that there is no information available as to what source code file from the java libraries this stack frame belongs to. The line before the `at …` should have given you more details about what the error actually *is.*

Answer (score 6):

One thing for sure wrong is:

```
wort[0] == "A"
```

should be

```
wort[0].equals( "A")
```

`String` comparison always should use `equals()` instead of `==` (except case of String literal comparison)

Regarding updated exception, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852453/accesscontroller-doprivileged) (or) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169717/why-does-my-applet-get-a-java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-ja) discussion may help.

Comment: hm that wasn't it but thanks :)

Comment: @LennartSchoch.. hmm. For more detailed answer, please post more detail in your question. We can't help without that. But this answer is useful. You should compare string using `equals` only.