# Why's Clojure failing from JNLP now?

Tags: java, clojure, jnlp, clojure-java-interop

I've got a Java app that's been in use for awhile and uses embedded Clojure scripts for some of the calculations.  Old versions of it still run fine with the current JRE, but if I go to build a new version (only changes to the code are in unrelated Java code) it fails to launch properly.  It also runs perfectly fine locally.  Only JNLP is affected.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at clojure.core$generate_proxy.invoke(core_proxy.clj:137)
    at clojure.core$get_proxy_class.doInvoke(core_proxy.clj:261)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
    at clojure.core$proxy.doInvoke(core_proxy.clj:335)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1152)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:465)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:248)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand1(Compiler.java:6468)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6546)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6322)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5708)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6009)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6560)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6548)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6322)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5708)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5139)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3751)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6558)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6548)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.access$100(Compiler.java:37)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:529)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6560)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6322)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6623)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__1451.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$eval1658.invoke(core.clj:6154)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:447)
    at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:329)
    at myapp(myapp.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The line that it's failing on is this:

```
RT.loadResourceScript("myapp/clojure_scripts.clj"); // Initialize Clojure script processor with our script
```

We're currently using a self-signed cert for this app (I've been working with Comodo for the last week trying to get a trusted cert to see if that helps, but I've still not received it and I need this app working ASAP).  What's odd to me is that old versions (also self-signed the exact same way) work.  I just can't build a new version.  I've rolled back my configs so that only actual java code changes should be different, but still no luck.  I'm missing something somewhere...

Comment: I've now also tried elevating privileges on it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852453/accesscontroller-doprivileged), with no effect.

Comment: I still wouldn't mind an answer, but ran out of time to try and solve this problem.  I had to port all my Clojure code into pure Java and abandon using Clojure in my JNLP application.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put this into your .jnlp-file:

`<security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>`

Additionally, depending on your security settings or if using Java 8, add

`:manifest {"Permissions" "all-permissions"}`

to your project.clj. Clojure requires you to give it the "all-permissions" permission. I'm not entirely sure if it's necessary for all Clojure applications, but I needed to also AOT my project to make it work in a JNLP application. Add this to your ":profiles :uberjar":

`:aot :all
:omit-sources true`